# Construct new columns based on all previous pairs information using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create 3 new columns in a dataframe, which are based on previous pairs information.

You can think of the dataframe as the results of comptetion ('xx' column) within diffrerent types ('type' column) at different dates ('date column).

The idea is to create the following new columns:

(i) numb_comp_past: sum of the number of times every type faced the competitors in the past.

(ii) win_comp_past: sum of the win (+1), ties (+0), and loss (-1) of the previous competitions that all the types competing with each other had in the past.

(iii) win_comp_past_difs: sum of difference of the results of the previous competitions that all the types competing with each other had in the past.

- The original dataframe (df) is the following:

  ```
  idx = [np.array(['Jan-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'Mar-18','Mar-18', 'Mar-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jun-18','Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18','Oct-18', 'Oct-18', 'Nov-18', 'Dec-18', 'Dec-18',]),np.array(['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'])]
  data = [{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 5}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 3},{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 6}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 5}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 3},{'xx': 1}, {'xx': 9}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 3}, {'xx': 6}, {'xx': 8}, {'xx': 2}, {'xx': 7}, {'xx': 9}]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['xx'])
  df.index.names=['date','type']
  df=df.reset_index()
  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format = '%b-%y') 
  df=df.set_index(['date','type'])
  df['xx'] = df.xx.astype('float')
  ```

And it looks like this:

```
                  xx
date       type
2018-01-01 A     1.0
           B     5.0
2018-02-01 B     3.0
2018-03-01 A     2.0
           B     7.0
           C     3.0
           D     1.0
           E     6.0
2018-05-01 B     3.0
2018-06-01 A     5.0
           B     2.0
           C     3.0
2018-07-01 A     1.0
2018-08-01 B     9.0
           C     3.0
2018-09-01 A     2.0
           B     7.0
2018-10-01 C     3.0
           A     6.0
           B     8.0
2018-11-01 A     2.0
2018-12-01 B     7.0
           C     9.0
```

- The 3 new columns I need to add to the dataframe are shown below (expected output of the Pandas code):

  ```
                    xx  numb_comp_past  win_comp_past  win_comp_past_difs
  date       type
  2018-01-01 A     1.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
             B     5.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-02-01 B     3.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-03-01 A     2.0             1.0           -1.0                -4.0
             B     7.0             1.0            1.0                 4.0
             C     3.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
             D     1.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
             E     6.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-05-01 B     3.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-06-01 A     5.0             3.0           -3.0               -10.0
             B     2.0             3.0            3.0                13.0
             C     3.0             2.0            0.0                -3.0
  2018-07-01 A     1.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-08-01 B     9.0             2.0            0.0                 3.0
             C     3.0             2.0            0.0                -3.0
  2018-09-01 A     2.0             3.0           -1.0                -6.0
             B     7.0             3.0            1.0                 6.0
  2018-10-01 C     3.0             5.0           -1.0               -10.0
             A     6.0             6.0           -2.0               -10.0
             B     8.0             7.0            3.0                20.0
  2018-11-01 A     2.0             0.0            0.0                 0.0
  2018-12-01 B     7.0             4.0            2.0                14.0
             C     9.0             4.0           -2.0               -14.0
  ```

Note that:

(i) for numb_comp_past if there are no previous competitions I assign a value of 0. On 2018-06-01, for example, the type A has a value of 3 given that he previously competed with type B on 2018-01-01 and 2018-03-01 and with type C on 2018-03-01.

(ii) for win_comp_past if there are no previous competitions I assign a value of 0. On 2018-06-01, for example, the type A has a value of -3 given that he previously lost with type B on 2018-01-01 (-1) and 2018-03-01 (-1) and with type C on 2018-03-01 (-1). Thus adding -1-1-1=-3.

(iii) for win_comp_past_value if there are no previous competitions I assign a value of 0. On 2018-06-01, for example, the type A has a value of -10 given that he previously lost with type B on 2018-01-01 by a difference of -4 (=1-5) and on 2018-03-01 by a diffrence of -5 (=2-7) and with type C on 2018-03-01 by -1 (=2-3). Thus adding -4-5-1=-10.

I really don't know how to start solving this problem. Any ideas of how to solve the new columns decribed in (i), (ii) and (ii) are very welcome.

Comment: You've posted a lot of questions the last couple of days. Can you post the code have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: In some questions I actually write my code, which work fine (please look at my previous posts), and only ask for improving performance using Pandas, but this time I really don't know how to start.

Comment: On 2018-06-01 type A previusly competed with type B two times (2018-01-01 and 2018-03-01) and previously competed with type C one time (2018-03-01). Thus 2+1=3

Comment: Because in previous dates they didn't competed. Note that: on 2018-01-01 A compted with B, on 2018-02-01 B had no competitors, on 2018-03-01 A competed with B, C, D , and E, etc

Comment: Note that I am looking past information of competitions (not current)

Comment: How big is each group?

Comment: On 2018-01-01 the competitors are 2 (A and B), on 2018-02-01 the competitor is only 1 (B), on 2018-03-01 the competitors are 5 (A, B, C, D, and E),etc. Is it that what are you asking for?

Comment: yes, but I'm asking in your real data? And also you data length. Size can make a solution not feasible.

Comment: I have around 20 thousand diffrent kind-of-dates (not exactly a date as I show here in my real data). Each date has around 10 "competitors" on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
# get differences of pairs, useful for win counts and win_difs
def get_diff(x):
    teams = x.index.get_level_values(1)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(x[:,None]-x[None,:],
                       columns = teams.values,
                       index=teams.values).stack()
    return tmp[tmp.index.get_level_values(0)!=tmp.index.get_level_values(1)]

new_df = df.groupby('date').xx.apply(get_diff).to_frame()

# win matches
new_df['win'] = new_df.xx.ge(0).astype(int) - new_df.xx.le(0).astype(int)

# group by players
groups = new_df.groupby(level=[1,2])

# sum function
def cumsum_shift(x):
    return x.cumsum().shift()

# assign new values
df['num_comp_past'] = groups.xx.cumcount().sum(level=[0,1])
df['win_comp_past'] = groups.win.apply(cumsum_shift).sum(level=[0,1])
df['win_comp_past_difs'] = groups.xx.apply(cumsum_shift).sum(level=[0,1])
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+-----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|            |      | xx  | num_comp_past | win_comp_past | win_comp_past_difs |
+------------+------+-----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| date       | type |     |               |               |                    |
+------------+------+-----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 2018-01-01 | A    | 1.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | B    | 5.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
| 2018-02-01 | B    | 3.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-03-01 | A    | 2.0 | 1.0           | -1.0          | -4.0               |
|            | B    | 7.0 | 1.0           | 1.0           | 4.0                |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | D    | 1.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | E    | 6.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
| 2018-05-01 | B    | 3.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-06-01 | A    | 5.0 | 3.0           | -3.0          | -10.0              |
|            | B    | 2.0 | 3.0           | 3.0           | 13.0               |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | -3.0               |
| 2018-07-01 | A    | 1.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-08-01 | B    | 9.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | 3.0                |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | -3.0               |
| 2018-09-01 | A    | 2.0 | 3.0           | -1.0          | -6.0               |
|            | B    | 7.0 | 3.0           | 1.0           | 6.0                |
| 2018-10-01 | C    | 3.0 | 5.0           | -1.0          | -10.0              |
|            | A    | 6.0 | 6.0           | -2.0          | -10.0              |
|            | B    | 8.0 | 7.0           | 3.0           | 20.0               |
| 2018-11-01 | A    | 2.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-12-01 | B    | 7.0 | 4.0           | 2.0           | 14.0               |
|            | C    | 9.0 | 4.0           | -2.0          | -14.0              |
| 2018-01-01 | A    | 1.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | B    | 5.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
| 2018-02-01 | B    | 3.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-03-01 | A    | 2.0 | 1.0           | -1.0          | -4.0               |
|            | B    | 7.0 | 1.0           | 1.0           | 4.0                |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | D    | 1.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
|            | E    | 6.0 | 0.0           | 0.0           | 0.0                |
| 2018-05-01 | B    | 3.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-06-01 | A    | 5.0 | 3.0           | -3.0          | -10.0              |
|            | B    | 2.0 | 3.0           | 3.0           | 13.0               |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | -3.0               |
| 2018-07-01 | A    | 1.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-08-01 | B    | 9.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | 3.0                |
|            | C    | 3.0 | 2.0           | 0.0           | -3.0               |
| 2018-09-01 | A    | 2.0 | 3.0           | -1.0          | -6.0               |
|            | B    | 7.0 | 3.0           | 1.0           | 6.0                |
| 2018-10-01 | C    | 3.0 | 5.0           | -1.0          | -10.0              |
|            | A    | 6.0 | 6.0           | -2.0          | -10.0              |
|            | B    | 8.0 | 7.0           | 3.0           | 20.0               |
| 2018-11-01 | A    | 2.0 | NaN           | NaN           | NaN                |
| 2018-12-01 | B    | 7.0 | 4.0           | 2.0           | 14.0               |
|            | C    | 9.0 | 4.0           | -2.0          | -14.0              |
+------------+------+-----+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Great job Quang Hoang, brilliant!